# Data result table containing sub tables in TSQL?

Tags: t-sql, join, subset, sublist

I am working on a products page that I have to query all data at once and one of the columns should contain multiple values. In this particular case it's a list of products containing multiple pictures. Unfortunately I cannot squeeze all pictures in the same column to slice it later because the data will be processed in a XML.CONFIG page that handle data with for-each. That's what I have.

In short I would like if there is a way of select data in a way where each record has a "sublist".

Example...

PRODUCT TABLE:

```
Id  ProdId  Desc
1   9003    Shirt
2   9004    Trouser
```

PICTURE TABLE:

```
Id  PicId   ProdId
1   A       9003
2   B       9003
3   C       9004
4   D       9004
5   E       9003
```

RESULT OF THE QUERY:

```
ProdId  Desc    PicId
9003    Shirt   
                A
                B
                E
9004    Trouser 
                C
                D
```

I know that it may sound crazy but I remember that around 20 years ago I made something similar using SQL Server Express and Crystal Reports in a VB program for church administration. We had a report listing congregational members and grouping their donations below each member. I am SURE that everything I did was to run a SQL query that did this job but it was so many time ago and I can't remember how it was done.

Any idea?

NOTE ADDED:

I just remembered that by the time I used the command "SHAPE". I found a sample in T-SQL documentation but don't know why it's not working. My code:

```
SHAPE {SELECT ProdId,Desc FROM product} AS PRO
APPEND ({SELECT PicId FROM pics} AS PIC
RELATE PRO.ProdId TO PIC.ProdId)
```

This is weird. I am doing exactly as the example but it says there is a sintax error near to }.

The T-SQL documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/mt-mt/sql/ado/guide/data/shape-append-clause?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: The is a task for the presentation layer, not the RDBMS.

Comment: *"The T-SQL documentation:"* That isn't Transact-SQL documentation; it's for ADO.

Comment: Ouch, yes, I totally missed this! :-( Thanks, I will try another approach

Comment: PS: Post it as an answer so I can accept it as solved. I believe it will value some points for you. ;-)

Comment: I haven't given an answer here to post one, Yan .

Answer (score 0):

That's a simple left join on `prodid`.

```
SELECT pr.prodid,
       pr.desc,
       pi.picid
       FROM product pr
            LEFT JOIN picture pi
                      ON pi.prodid = pr.prodid
       ORDER BY pr.prodid,
                pi.picid;
```

which will get you

| prodid | desc | left |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9003 | Shirt | A |
| 9003 | Shirt | B |
| 9003 | Shirt | E |
| 9004 | Trouser | C |
| 9004 | Trouser | D |

The rest is presentation layer logic as @Larnu commented. You'd basically loop through the result and print the header line for a product each time you encounter one that wasn't already processed. In either case print the picture line.

Comment: I know how to perform a join but this is not what I am after. Your query generated 5 records and it should have only 2 (I think my example is very clear in this sense). Anyway I am trying the SHAPE command from TSQL documentation (and that I remember it was what I used by the time) but for some reason it's not working.

Comment: @YanKleber: Your example result has seven rows... And yeah, this transformation, from the five to the seven, is, as I wrote, to be handled by the presentation layer.

Comment: No, it has TWO rows with subsets in each. Sorry if I cannot be more clear about this. Also it CAN be done in T-SQL with SHAPE command. I just am not managing to realize why it's not working. See the note I appended in my OP.

Comment: @YanKleber: To my knowledge there is no such thing as subsets in a column of a row in SQL Server (Oracle does know nested tables bu not SQL Server). So the only logical interpretation of your result is seven rows, not two. But OK, I get how you meant it now, it's difficult to present that here. But still I guess you want to show that result in some program, so fetching a *possible* relational result and processing it as described is a way to go.

Comment: Sure, no problem, thanks. Larnu nailed the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: The problem is that it is going to be done within a XML.CONFIG using poor XPATH and basically everything I can do for this job is loop through XML with a for-each. I will query a separate dataset with all pictures and loop checking what records matches the productid of each product. It's an ugly solution and I was after something more neat. No problem at all, maybe just a bit of preciosism. LoL. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL 2017 you can use the STRING_AGG function.  If not then I would use the FOR XML clause such as:

```
CREATE TABLE #PRODUCT(Id int, ProdId int, [Desc] varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #PRODUCT VALUES
(1,9003,'Shirt'),
(2,9004,'Trouser')

CREATE TABLE #PICTURE(Id int,  PicId varchar(4),   ProdId int)
INSERT INTO #PICTURE VALUES
(1,'A', 9003),
(2,'B', 9003),
(3,'C', 9004),
(4,'D', 9004),
(5,'E', 9003)
```

**FOR SQL 2017 and above:**

```
select p.id,p.ProdId, STRING_AGG(pt.PicID, CHAR(13)) PicID
from #PRODUCT p
INNER JOIN #PICTURE PT on p.ProdId = pt.ProdId 
GROUP BY p.Id,p.ProdId
```

**FOR SQL 2016 and below:**

```
SELECT p.id,p.ProdId,   
        STUFF(
             (SELECT  CHAR(13) +  pt.PicID 
              FROM #PICTURE pt
              WHERE p.ProdId = pt.ProdId
              FOR XML PATH ('')) 
             , 1, 1, '') PicID
    FROM #PRODUCT p
GROUP BY p.Id,p.ProdId
```